# ServiceBus Broker service failed to start, retry count 2. Exception message: Service type is already registered

Tags: 2013, workflow, service

Due to outage last night my workflow servers are having issues. Service Bus Broker Service is stuck at starting stage, But Service gateway and app fabric services are started.

Here are some error i have listed in event viewer:

```
    ServiceBus Broker service failed to start, retry count 2.  Exception message: Service type is already registered..  Stack Trace:    at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1 func, String functionTag)
   at Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.MessageContainerHost.Ring.Join()
   at Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.MessageContainerHost.MessageContainerHostComponent.Open()
   at Microsoft.Cloud.HostingModel.ComponentHost.OpenComponent(IComponent component, RequestTracker tracker)
   at Microsoft.Cloud.HostingModel.ComponentHost.Open()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.MessageBroker.Backend.OnStart(String[] args)



    Windows Fabric service registration failed. Exception System.Fabric.FabricException: Service type is already registered. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071BD1
   at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeRuntime.IFabricRuntime.RegisterStatefulServiceFactory(IntPtr serviceType, IFabricStatefulServiceFactory factory)
   at System.Fabric.FabricRuntime.InternalRegisterServiceFactory(Boolean isStateful, String serviceType, ServiceFactoryBroker serviceFactoryBroker)
   at System.Fabric.FabricRuntime.RegisterServiceTypeHelper(Boolean isStateful, String serviceTypeName, Type serviceTypeImplementation)
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.<>c__DisplayClassad.<WrapNativeSyncInvoke>b__ac()
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1 func, String functionTag)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1 func, String functionTag)
   at Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.MessageContainerHost.Ring.Join()



TrackingId: fa3ed858-16c3-4926-9b4a-895ec44d1904_BW00001Q07, SubsystemId: NoSystemTracker. Failed to open Messaging Host Component System.Fabric.FabricException: Service type is already registered. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071BD1
   at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeRuntime.IFabricRuntime.RegisterStatefulServiceFactory(IntPtr serviceType, IFabricStatefulServiceFactory factory)
   at System.Fabric.FabricRuntime.InternalRegisterServiceFactory(Boolean isStateful, String serviceType, ServiceFactoryBroker serviceFactoryBroker)
   at System.Fabric.FabricRuntime.RegisterServiceTypeHelper(Boolean isStateful, String serviceTypeName, Type serviceTypeImplementation)
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.<>c__DisplayClassad.<WrapNativeSyncInvoke>b__ac()
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1 func, String functionTag)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1 func, String functionTag)
   at Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.MessageContainerHost.Ring.Join()
   at Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.MessageContainerHost.MessageContainerHostComponent.Open()
```